# Как использовать провайдер IVsPackageSourceProvider

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-extensions, компоненты

Привет! Как с помощью `IVsPackageSourceProvider` я могу получить список источников NuGet пакетов?
Пробую использовать вот такую конструкцию:

```
    using (Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider provider = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider((Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)base._dteObject))
    {

        IComponentModel service = (IComponentModel)provider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
        try
        {
            var sourceProvider = service.GetService<IVsPackageSourceProvider>();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Но в блоке `try` падает `Exception` с текстом:

> Cannot cast the underlying exported value of type
>   'NuGet.VisualStudio.VsPackageSourceProvider
>   (ContractName="NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageSourceProvider")' to type
>   'NuGet.VisualStudio.IVsPackageSourceProvider'

Подскажите как правильно использовать этот провайдер.

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Причина проблемы, как я понял, кроется в `Visual Studio 2012/2013` и `NuGet Manager 2.12.0.817`.

Причем проект успешно собирается с такими строками, однако во время исполнения на указанных продуктах успешно падает.

Корректно работает на `Visual Studio 2015` и `NuGet Manager 3.4.4.1321`.